# javascript smooth scroll

Tags: javascript

I would like to implement smooth scrolling on my page made in drupal 6. I have a list of topics on top of the page. I would like the page to smooth scroll down direction to the topic. Can any point me how to do it in drupal 6?
thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I picked one of many js scripts available on internet. Then put it into js file inside theme directory + added this to theme.php

function MYTHEME_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
  drupal_add_js('...');
  $variables['scripts'] = drupal_get_js();
flush caches and it is working.

Answer (score 0):

Try customising the [Scroll to Top](http://drupal.org/project/scroll_to_top) module. Which provides a similar functionality.

Answer (score 0):

If the [Scroll to Top](http://drupal.org/project/scroll_to_top) module mentioned by @vgardner isn't to your liking, you might also look at integrating Ariel Flesler's [jQuery.scrollTo](http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/) plugin which may offer a lot more functionality out of the box.